# javascript: create automattic substrings for every string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

is it possible to create automatic substrings in javascript for every string in an array?
for example:

```
var test = 
[
 "banana",
 "apple",
 "pear",
 "cologne"
];

var conclusion = prompt("choose one")

// something that would get the following result:

if( conclusion === banana)

{

print("b");

print("ba");

print ("ban");

// ...

print("banana");

// and the same for the rest of the strings in the Array.
```

Comment: Learn about loops and string functions.

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a short solution, I let you understand by yourself as a homework :

```js
var test ="banana";
test.split("").forEach((x,i,arr) => console.log(arr.slice(0,i+1).join("")));
```

Comment: hahahahaha thank you! i've started like 6 days ago learning javascript on my own, and before that i learnt Pascal and a tiny bit of SQL, so thank you for the great solution and for letting me explore its command's purpose and meaning :)

Comment: Welcome on stack. Don't hesitate to ask again. You'll always be answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the idea is to take the character length of an item chosen and follow this ,

```
var test ="banana"; 
for(var i=0;i<=test.length;i++)
{
console.log(test.substring(0,i));
}
```

This is for one item and is applicable to any element in an array.

Comment: thank you for your answer, and even though it works, there's a shorter answer, and size matters:P